Get selection name of a textbox using OpenXml in powerpoint
I am trying to read and write to text boxes in a Powerpoint presentation using OpenXML. To find the text boxes in the presentation, I want to use the name of the selection. I have checked several NonVisualProperties without success. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
enter image description here
I try to get the name "TextBox 1"

Powerpoint is a Microsoft Office product that uses a proprietary format that is not compatible with OpenXml.  Best solution is to use the PowerPoint InterOp.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ff764034(v=office.12)

@jdweng PowerPoint documents are in OpenXML format. The OpenXML SDK facilitates working directly with Office documents.

@PeterDongan : PowerPoint files are NOT OpenXml.

@jdweng What are you talking about when you say OpenXML? PowerPoint files do use OpenXML. I have an answer on this page describing how to find what he is looking for in the structure of one, with a bunch of links about the OpenXML structure of a PowerPoint document. (The MIME type of a pptx file is even application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation)

@PeterDongan : Read what you said.  It does not say Power Point is OpenXML : "The OpenXML SDK facilitates working directly with Office documents."

@jdweng Your link points to an article about previous versions of PowerPoint (as it even says IN the URL). PowerPoint files with a PPT extension ARE entirely different and are definitely not any flavor of XML. Current versions (since Office 2007) are ZIP files containing a collection of XML and other files. One might debate whether these are "true" OpenXML or a Microsoft variant, but they ARE XML.

The textbox is a shape object. You can find its name in the following property:
Shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Name

Here is a console application that demonstrates this. It lists all the names of textboxes in the first slide of a file named test1.pptx in C:\temp:
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using System.Text;

string filepath = @"C:\Temp\test1.pptx";

ListTextBoxIds( filepath, 0);


static void ListTextBoxIds( string docName, int index)
{
    using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(docName, false))
    {
        // Get the relationship ID of the first slide.
        PresentationPart? part = ppt.PresentationPart;
        OpenXmlElementList slideIds = part?.Presentation?.SlideIdList?.ChildElements ?? default;

        if (part is null || slideIds.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        string? relId = ((SlideId)slideIds[index]).RelationshipId;

        if (relId is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Get the slide part from the relationship ID.
        SlidePart slide = (SlidePart)part.GetPartById(relId);

        // Get the inner text of the slide:
        IEnumerable<Shape> shapes = slide.Slide.Descendants<Shape>();
        foreach (Shape s in shapes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Name);
        }

    }
}

A good way to learn about the OpenXML structure of Office documents is to rename them .zip and and look at the contents, which will be a bunch of xml files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.presentation.shape?view=openxml-3.0.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.presentation.shape.nonvisualshapeproperties?view=openxml-3.0.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.presentation.nonvisualshapeproperties.nonvisualdrawingproperties?view=openxml-3.0.1

@Markus I added sample code that demonstrates that it works.

In case you need to get Text Box by name, you can also use the open-source library ShapeCrawler:
var pres = new Presentation("my-pres.pptx");

var textBox = pres.Slide(1).Shape("TextBox 1");

